# remove email address format from username

Tags: javascript

```js
var login_id = 'sa-testaccount0125@abc.com';
console.log(login_id.substring(0, login_id.lastIndexOf("@")));
```

Above script works perfectly if I pass input with `'@abc.com'`. Does not work if string do not have `'@domain.com'`
We have some user name with `username@domain.com` and few are just username. I want extract `@domain.com` from user name. Expected output is if input is `username@domain.com`  return `output = username` and if input is username, output should be username.

Please help if there is any way.

Comment: Do you want to remove `@domain.com` from username?

Comment: Yes, it working but if user name does not have @domain.com it does not work. Basically I am trying to process both type of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .split() method to split your string in parts

It will still work if you do not have @domain.com

#### Case-1:

```js
const login_id = 'sa-testaccount0125@abc.com';
console.log(login_id.split("@")[0])
```

Output

```js
"sa-testaccount0125"
```

#### Case-2:

```js
const login_id = 'sa-testaccount0125';
console.log(login_id.split("@")[0])
```

Output

```js
"sa-testaccount0125"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you split on `@` then you get an array of items. The first item of the array will be the username, whether there was a `@` in it or not.

```js
const test = str => str.split('@')[0]

console.log(test('sa-testaccount0125@abc.com'));
console.log(test('sa-testaccount0125'));
```

Answer (score 0):

#### check first if it contains the '@' charactar first

```
    login_id.includes('@') ? console.log(login_id.substring(0, 
      login_id.lastIndexOf("@"))) : console.log(login_id) ;
```

**Running example**

```js
function username(login_id) {
  return login_id.includes('@') ? login_id.substring(0,login_id.lastIndexOf("@")) :  login_id ;
   }


console.log(username("sa-testaccount0125@abc.com")) ;
console.log(username("sa-testaccount0125")) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a `indexOf`. Usee that to check `@` if exists as well:

```js
function check(login_id) {
  if (login_id.indexOf('@') >= 0) {

    return login_id.substring(0, login_id.lastIndexOf("@"));
  }
  return login_id;
}

console.log(check('sa-testaccount0125@asdasdasd.com'));
console.log(check('sa-asd'));
console.log(check('sa-asasd@domain.com'));
```